# How to add Qt5 to Qt Creator?

Tags: application-development, qt, qt-creator, qt5

I've added the [Qt5 Daily repository](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-qt5-edgers/+archive/qt5-daily), installed the `qt5-meta-full` and added `/opt/qt5/bin/qmake` to Qt Versions.
Now I get

```
:-1: error: Unknown module(s) in QT: declarative
```

Is it possible yet to use Qt5 with Qt Creator?

Comment: "apt-get install qtquick1-5-dev" makes that specific build error go away, I think

Comment: Thanks Erik, that helped me since I got the same error above. (Missing Qt Declarative.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but not the version of Qt Creator in the archives. Qt 5.0 is compatible **only** with Qt Creator 2.6.1+. Thankfully, installing Qt Creator 2.6.1 is relatively easy:

1. Remove the existing version of Qt Creator you have installed:

   ```
   sudo apt-get autoremove qtcreator
   ```
2. Download the appropriate installer from [this page](http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator):

   - [32-bit Linux Installer](http://releases.qt-project.org/qtcreator/2.6.1/qt-creator-linux-x86-opensource-2.6.1.bin)
   - [64-bit Linux Installer](http://releases.qt-project.org/qtcreator/2.6.1/qt-creator-linux-x86_64-opensource-2.6.1.bin)
3. `cd` into the directory that contains the installer you downloaded and run:

   ```
   chmod 755 qt-creator-linux-*-opensource-2.6.1.bin
   ```
4. Launch the installer:

   ```
   sudo ./qt-creator-linux-*-opensource-2.6.1.bin
   ```
5. Complete the installer, leaving all settings at their defaults.

If all goes well, you should end up with an icon in your desktop environment's dash or equivalent. You should then be able to use Qt 5.0 with Qt Creator.

Comment: Strangely, I still had Qt Creator 2.4 in Dash after this. But running `bin/qtcreator` from the installation directory launches 2.6.1. Checking it.

Comment: Looks like ok. I wanted Qt Quick 2.0 and it's not installed. But that's another question. Do you know if that's available?